# Stop elements from moving around when page is resized

Tags: css

The elements on my website keep moving around when I resize the page.
I want them to stay fixed, regardless of the screen resolution. Here is the CSS code of my website:

I tried using a wrapper, but it messes everything up.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
#leftmenu {
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    width:150px;
    background-color:gray;

}
#leftmenu .titlebox {
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:black;
}
#leftmenu .titlebox .text {
    margin-left:10px;
    font-family:OswaldL;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}
/*Droite Debut*/
 #rightmenu {
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    width:220px;
    background-color:gray;
}
#rightmenu .titlebox {
    height:20px;
    width:250px;
    margin-right:2px;
    background-color:black;
}
#rightmenu .titlebox .text {
    margin-left:10px;
    font-family:OswaldL;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}

.rightt{
    right: 296px;
    margin-right:4px;
    position: absolute;
}

.leftt, .rightt {
    display: inline-block;
}

.milieu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Without your html to provide the structure, we can't help you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I've copied your CSS and HTML into jsfiddle and the elements are fixed. Your rightmenu id/div goes off-screen when the window adjusts however, your leftmenu moves with the viewport size. Do you want it so the right menu sticks to the viewport but stays fixed? Or do you want it so if you change the viewport it will just go off-screen like your leftmenu?

viewport = screen size

Answer (score 0):

from looking at your css i can tell that you are using fixed layout, so responsiveness will not work on them until you make it responsive by using

1. width in percentage
2. media queries

try to share html code so can get better help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="base">

    <div class="leftt">
        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text"><?php echo NOM_SITE;?></div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['pseudo']))
                {
            ?>

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">account</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



            <?php
                }   
            ?>

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">Int</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">abt</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>


</div>

<div class="rightt">
        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">Forums</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">other</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
            $connectes
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="milieu">
```

Here is the HTML :)